# What Material Design UI framework to use with Angular 2

Tags: user-interface, angular, material-design

I'm starting an Angular 2 project and wondering what framework to use for the user interface. (I'm new to Angular 2)

Since there are many options available I figured that you may have experience with some of them and help me choose.

I've used Materialize before w/o framework and it did the job just fine. 
Also looked into MDL, Bootstrap 4 with some material design theme and Angular Material

Which one should I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 come with Material Design Version1 currently in stable state. Angular Material version2 development is also in-progress But i would prefer to use bootstrap or foundation.You can easily install bootstrap using npm command

**Bootstrap**
`npm install bootstrap`

**Foundation**
`npm install foundation`

By installing libraries using npm, you can access them from **node_modules** folder by specifying path styles and script in **angular-cli.json** file.

```
 "styles": [

    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",

  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, really appreciate it. Do you recommend some particular bootstrap material themes?

Comment: it will depend on your requirement.

Comment: this may help you [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-material-design)

Comment: I was just looking into it. Their demo page is a total mess on mobile.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://mdbootstrap.com). `npm install mdbootstrap`You can accept the answer if it do's the job for you.

Comment: I have not yet decided what to use so looking for some more input on that. For now I'm planning to use either MDL or Materialize